# Show a flicker or ToolTip when user logs in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I have menus for pending requests when the user logs in. I want a smaller flicker/tooltip kind of thing or a ballon kind of thing just aroung that menu not the whole page, just to indicate the user and grabs his attention when he logs in. Once he notices that he find that he has some tasks pending. Now, I searched and tried a modal popup extender but I am not that happy. I also want that flicker to go away after 30 seconds or 1 minute. After evrytime the user logs in he see's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Ajax Hover Menu Extender control is is quite easier to implement
>   a Tooltip where you can embed HTML tags to get desired output. when
>   tooltip text is more, scroll bar is displayed to scroll through to
>   read complete text.

**Step 1**

After downloading, adding the Ajax Control toolkit to your ToolBox in Visual Studio, register AjaxControlToolKit on top of your aspx as below.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControl" %>
```

**strong text**Step 2

Add Script Manager on aspx page as below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Step 3**

Use Hover Menu Extender control where the TargetControl ID is your desired control, Tooltip text is displayed from the Label control and CSS class is for styling as shown below.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgName" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Tooltip.gif" />

<cc1:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender2" runat="server"
TargetControlID="imgName"  PopupControlID="lblTooltipTxt"
OffsetX="30" OffsetY="0" />

<asp:Label ID="lblTooltipTxt" runat="server" CssClass="tooltip"
            Text="Your Tooltip Text HERE"/>
```

Style sheet class

Here is the style sheet source code used for the tooltip.

```
.tooltip
{
border:2px solid #317082;   /* Border width */
left:18px;  /* Same as border thickness */
top:0px;
position:absolute;
width:500px;     /*Width of tooltip content */
height:100px;   /* Height of tooltip content */
background-color:#FFF;  /* Background color */
padding:5px;    /* Space between border and content */
font-size:1.0em;    /* Font size of content */
overflow:auto;  /* Hide overflow content */
z-index:1000001;

}
```

output

When you hover on the image tooltip is displayed.

Comment: I dont want the user to take the cursor/mouse pointer there. As soon as he logs in he should be able to see the popup/tooltip kind of thinglike you have when you refresh a page in IE with compatibility viwe.